# Current request is not a multipart request | Ajax | Spring Boot | Multipart | JQuery

Tags: jquery, ajax, spring-boot, multipartform-data, multipart

> org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartException: Current request is not a multipart request

The HTML contains around 50 or 60 elements including radio, checkbox, textarea, textbox and also multiple file types:

```
Upload File: <input id="partfiles" name="partfiles[]" type="file" class="file" multiple data-show-upload="true" data-show-caption="true">
                                
 SomeLabel: <form:input type="number" path="operationValue" class="form-control" placeholder="operationValue"></form:input>
```

jQuery:

```
dataType : 'text',
url : "/createpo",
enctype : 'multipart/form-data',
data : $("body form:first").serialize(),
```

Spring Boot Code:

```
@PostMapping("/createpo")
public String createPO(@ModelAttribute("purchaseOrderForm") PurchaseOrderForm purchaseOrderForm, BindingResult bindingResult, Model model, @RequestParam("partfiles") MultipartFile[] files) 
{
  System.out.println(purchaseOrderForm);
  System.out.println("Length:" + files.length);
```

There is no multipart in `purchaseOrderForm` model attribute.

When I request I get the following content type:

```
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8
```

I tried changing encoding type as given above but it has no effect.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed using following:

```
    var fromData  = new FormData($("#body form:first")[0]);
    documentCommon.ajax({
        dataType : 'text',
        url : "/createpo",
        contentType : false,
        processData: false,
        data: fromData,
```